# Can not find symbol DataSource

Tags: java, sql, maven, jdbc, datasource

I cant run the following code as I suppose I am missing a dependency (jar file), 
when I run the code it shows the following error

SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DataSource
  location : class com.myproject.model

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource; //and import javax.sql.DataSource both does not work

public class AuthModel {

    public Connection DbConnection(){
            Connection con = null;
        try {
                        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
cant find symbol Error >>   DataSource ds = new (DataSource)ctx.lookup("mydatabase");
                        con = ds.getConnection("root", "");
                        con.setAutoCommit(false);
                  .....
```

Dependencies

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/package-summary.html

Comment: @Brian Roach, I read that, the problem should be dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem of DataSource but I followed [1](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/jdbcdatasourceexample.html) to solve the problem using BasicDataSource, and it perfectly works now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating here but this looks like a classpath issue. I see you're importing `javax.sql`. Do you need to import `javax.sql.*` or specifically `javax.sql.DataSource`? Also, please ensure you do have the necessary jar.

Also, if you have two different packages with the same class, there is possibility of class conflicts. Have you tried renaming the variables along with the package path.. aka

```
public final static String MY_DATABASE = "mydatabase"
...
javax.sql.DataSource dataSource = new (javax.sql.DataSource)context.lookup(MY_DATABASE);
```

Also, one a side note, could you not use variables like con, ctx and AuthModel and use the fullnames aka AuthentionModel, XProject, connection, context, dataSource and so on.

Comment: it did not work, when I use javax.sql.* it shows the import is unused, when I use javax.sql.DataSource it asks for dependency, but I have already added the dependency on maven

Comment: do you need to add `javax.sql.DataSource` in your list of dependencies?